# JPA Entity not having the column from the table but query based on the non existing column in the entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entity, hql

I have an entity called `Person` which represent `person_tb`
`person_tb` has 10 fields that includes `zip` and `country`. But these columns are not specified in the `Person` entity. The entity contains only 8 columns out of 10 columns in the actual table.

Can I still run the query against person entity referring to the non-existing fields (but existing in the actual table)? (I am assuming its not possible)

If the above is not possible, can I write native query based on the missing fields in the entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - you can use [Native SQL Queries](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/vasiliev-jpql-087123.html) for this purpose.